# Rank an array of objects in Swift efficiently

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I'm trying to rank an array of objects for a leaderboard.

I have something that is working, but I'm wondering if it's possible to code something cleaner and more efficient. Maybe with map() ?

This is what I did:

I have a Score object:

```
class Score {
  value: Double
  username: String
  date: Date,
  position: Int?
}
```

And this is my code (it's working but maybe without efficiency with a lot of data):

```
let scores: [Score] = [*allMyScoreObjects*]()

var i = 0
for score in scores {
     if i > 0 {
       let previousScore = scores[i - 1]
       if previousScore.value == score.value {
           score.position = previousScore.position
       } else {
           score.position = i + 1
       }        
     } else {
         score.position = 1
     }
     i += 1
}
```

Would you have any advice?

Comment: Can you show some example output? Your current code doesn't seem to be ranking the scores' values. You are only comparing if every score is equal to the previous one...

Comment: Also, your Score struct does not have a `position` property, but your code sets a position property.

Comment: Yes my bad, I forgot to add the position property.
The output is an array of Score objects, updated with the right position

Comment: Your question is about `sort`, but you aren't sorting, you assume that `score` is already sorted (based on I guess `value`). You are assigning a `position` value which is a rank. A `reduce()` might do the trick.

Comment: Yes, It's hard to explain a problem a problem in English when it's not my native language. The array is already sorted, I want to assign a rank to the objects of my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify you issues, let's illustrate it at the same time:
`scores` is a array of scores sorted by `value`.
You want to know their position, who's first, who's second, etc, getting also the ex-aequo, keeping their rank.

Let's simplify your example:

```
class Score: CustomStringConvertible {
    var value: Double
    var position: Int?

    init(value: Double, position: Int? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.position = position
    }

    var description: String { return "Score(value:\(value), position: \(position))"}
}
```

I added `CustomStringConvertible` to have a "beautiful print".

And with initial input:

```
let scores = [Score(value: 0.1), //#1
              Score(value: 0.8), //#2
              Score(value: 0.8), //#2
              Score(value: 1.2), //#3
              Score(value: 6.7)] //#4
```

So target val

A possible way to do that is to use `reduce(into:_)`. I prefer it in this case, because it's easy to get "last" item.

```
let reduced1 = scores.reduce(into: [Score]()) { partialResult, aScore in
    defer { partialResult.append(aScore) }
    guard let last = partialResult.last else { aScore.position = 1; return }
    if last.value == aScore.value {
        aScore.position = last.position
    }
    else {
        aScore.position = (last.position ?? 0) + 1
    }
}

print(reduced1)
```

`partialResult` will grow at each iteration, and will be in the end `reduced1`. We check the last saved item in `partialResult`, and if there isn't, we set the default position to 1, and if there is one, we compare the value between the current one (`aScore`) and `last to know which position should` aScore` have.

Output:

```
$>[Score(value:0.1, position: Optional(1)), Score(value:0.8, position: Optional(2)), Score(value:0.8, position: Optional(2)), Score(value:1.2, position: Optional(3)), Score(value:6.7, position: Optional(4))]
```

Which could be simplified with:

```
let reduced2 = scores.reduce(into: [Score]()) { partialResult, aScore in
    if partialResult.last?.value == aScore.value {
        aScore.position = (partialResult.last?.position ?? 0) + 1
    }
    partialResult.append(aScore)
}

print(reduced2)
```

Which could be shorten with a `ternary if`:

```
let reduced3 = scores.reduce(into: [Score]()) { partialResult, aScore in
    aScore.position = partialResult.last?.value == aScore.value ? partialResult.last?.position : (partialResult.last?.position ?? 0) + 1
    partialResult.append(aScore)
}

print(reduced3)
```

And could also be shorter with the `Shorthand Argument Names` (using `$0` and `$1` in our case):

```
let reduced4 = scores.reduce(into: [Score]()) {
    $1.position = $0.last?.value == $1.value ? $0.last?.position : ($0.last?.position ?? 0) + 1
    $0.append($1)
}

print(reduced4)
```

I don't recommend the construction of `reduced3` & `reduced4` since it's hard to understand what's going on, and to debug, it's a nightmare. I might even keep `reduced1` or `reduced2` in my own code. I think that `reduced1` is clearer for anyone looking at the code. Also, compiling will make optimisation, so don't worry too much about it. I'd prioritize clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I am making two assumptions here, that your scores are already SORTED, and each score originally does not have a rank. Since you need to edit every score, the minimum complexity is O(N). It seems that your current complexity is O(N) since you are just iterating through the scores and looking up an array value which is O(1), so the real answer is no you cant improve efficiency.

The only improvement I could see is instead of "looking up" (scores[i-1]) the previous value, you can store it:

```
var i = 0
var previousScore: Double!
var previousPosition = 1
for score in scores {
     if i > 0 {
       if previousScore == score.value {
           score.position = previousPosition
       } else {
           score.position = i + 1
           previousScore = score.value
           previousPosition = i + 1
       }        
     } else {
         score.position = 1
         previousScore = score.value
     }
     i += 1
}
```